# corefine_and_compute_difference CGAL error: precondition violation

Tags: cgal

**Problem description**

I read the mesh from the file "blank.off" and load it into the a surface_mesh variable **blank**. One file named "hepoints49.txt" stores point clouds. I use function `CGAL::advancing_front_surface_reconstruction()` to convert this point cloud to surface_mesh **sv**, and then use function `corefine_and_compute_difference(blank,sv,res)` to perform the Boolean subtraction between **blank** and **sv**.But the program throws an exception and terminates. The following is displayed on the terminal:

```
Using context  4 . 3 GL
load sv...
Using context  4 . 3 GL
start difference...
CGAL error: precondition violation!
Expression : CGAL::is_valid_polygon_mesh(tm)
File       : D:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/orientation.h
Line       : 190
```

Could you please help me solve this problem?

**code**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<io.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<array>
#include<CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include<CGAL/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction.h>
#include<CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include<CGAL/disable_warnings.h>
#include<CGAL/draw_surface_mesh.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<string>
#include<CGAL/polygon_mesh_processing/corefinement.h>
#include<CGAL/polygon_mesh_processing/remesh.h>
#include<CGAL/boost/graph/selection.h>
#include<CGAL/polygon_mesh_processing/repair_self_intersections.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

namespace PMP = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing;

typedef std::array<std::size_t, 3> Facet;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3> Mesh;

struct Construct {
    Mesh& mesh;

    template <typename PointIterator>
    Construct(Mesh& mesh, PointIterator b, PointIterator e):mesh(mesh) {
        for (; b != e; ++b) {
            boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertex_descriptor v;
            v = add_vertex(mesh);
            mesh.point(v) = *b;
        }
    }

    Construct& operator=(const Facet f) {
        typedef boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertex_descriptor vertex_descriptor;
        typedef boost::graph_traits<Mesh>::vertices_size_type size_type;
        mesh.add_face(vertex_descriptor(static_cast<size_type>(f[0])),
            vertex_descriptor(static_cast<size_type>(f[1])),
            vertex_descriptor(static_cast<size_type>(f[2])));
        return *this;
    }
    
    Construct& operator*() { return *this; }
    Construct& operator++() { return *this; }
    Construct& operator++(int) { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    
    //load blank
    Mesh blank, sv,res;
    std::ifstream fin("blank.off");
    fin>>blank;
    fin.close();

    CGAL::draw(blank);

    //load sv
    string filename = "hepoints49.txt" ;
    std::cout << "load sv..."<< std::endl;
    fin.open(filename);
    std::vector<Point_3> points;
    std::vector<Facet> facets;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Point_3>(fin),
        std::istream_iterator<Point_3>(),
        std::back_inserter(points));//load points
    fin.close();
    Construct construct(sv, points.begin(), points.end());
    CGAL::advancing_front_surface_reconstruction(points.begin(), points.end(), construct);//convert sv to surface_mesh
    CGAL::draw(sv);

    std::cout << "start difference..." << std::endl;
    bool valid_difference = PMP::corefine_and_compute_difference(blank,sv,res);

    if (valid_difference) {
        std::cout << "difference was successfully computed. " << std::endl;
        CGAL::draw(res);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "difference could not be completed. Skip. " << endl << endl;
    }
    
    //CGAL::draw(res);
    return 0;
}
```

**Runtime environment**

CGAL version: 5.3

IDE: VS2017

Solution Configuration: Debug x64

I tried to run this program in Release mode, of course there is no exception thrown. But the result I got turned out to be the opposite of what I want.

**Files**

Files that appearing in the code are provided below:

```
https://github.com/wenzaifou/for-stack-overflow-question3.git
```

Github link is provided because the file is relatively large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the mesh is constructed from advancing front output does not filter out isolated vertices, which causes the exception to be raised. Adding a call to `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::`[`remove_isolated_vertices(sv)`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html#ga91c02ef57e638faf2622eae93e7a25e2) will solve the problem.

Then you might encounter the issue that your meshes are not outward oriented (meaning then represent an infinite portion of space). Adding the following calls will solve the problem:

```
if (!CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::is_outward_oriented(blank))
  CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::reverse_face_orientations(blank);
if (!CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::is_outward_oriented(sv))
  CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::reverse_face_orientations(sv);
```

Doc refs [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#ga53a77073bf9a4118ecf949b851e1f5d9) and [there](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#ga21119757bf5835496ae1c9a6d4f5fa0a).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Using your advice, most cases can be calculated correctly, but there are still some cases that go wrong. For example, if I use **blank2.off** instead of **blank.off** and **hepoints82. txt** instead of **hepoints49.txt**, the following is displayed on the terminal:

`CGAL error: assertion violation!

Expression : res!=boost::none

File       : D:\dev\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\CGAL/Kernel/function_objects.h

Line       : 1719`

New files [here](https://github.com/wenzaifou/for-stack-overflow-question4.git)

Comment: `blank2.off` has self-intersections. You must repair it before doing the Boolean operations. You can can try `CGAL::Polygon_processing_processing::experimental::remove_degenerate_faces()` followed by `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::experimentatl::remove_self_intersections()`. Note that corefinement based functions have a named parameter so that an exception is thrown in case some self-intersections that might be problematic for the operation are detected.